# google script ssl error connecting to gitlab api

Tags: google-apps-script, gitlab-api

I'm using google scripts to connect to a gitlab endpoint hosted in my VM in Azure. However, I'm encountering an SSL error when I run it.

```
 var url = "https://[the ip address of my gitlab instance]/api/v4/projects/2/issues";

var option = {
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': [Personal Access Token],
    'validateHttpsCertificates' : false,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  }
}
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option).getContentText();
```

1. How do I see more details of the underlying cause of the SSL?
2. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Try a google search "ssl error connecting gitlab google apps script" there seems to be a lot written about errors of that nature.

Comment: Can you provide the detailed error message? And, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?